# Retrofit / Robospice handle multiple response objects

Tags: android

How do I make Retrofit / Robospice handle my api responses in a way that I can get an empty JSON response body like: `{}`, but also a regular JSON response body?

Currently the empty response body initialises a new POJO, but I only want this to happen if there is actually a filled response body.

I have an object that contains three booleans, and these will always be set to false, while this shouldn't happen.

I somehow have the idea this is caused by my GSON deserializer (I use the default one), but don't know where to start for something like this.

Thanks for any help. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not using Boolean instead of boolean? That way the default value in `null` rather than `false`

Comment: always prefer to use primitive types over class types.

Comment: I agree, but for this solution it actually works, else I'd have to initialise the object, while actually I expect a null object.

Thanks, it feels bad I had to turn to Stackoverflow for something so simple as this :')

Answer (score 0):

`Retrofit` doesn't touch fields if there's no such fields in `json`. So init them by yourself.

```
public class Response {
  public boolean value = true;
}
```

Comment: but `true` or `false` are bad values for him. they actually mean something else than `null`